# Does Fortify support DNX?

Tags: .net, security, .net-core, fortify

Can Fortify be used to scan security vulnerabilities in a dnx project? So far, I have not come across any examples or discussions regarding this. If not, are there any other tools that can be used for scanning for vulnerabilities in a dnx project?

Comment: You probably mean .NET Core, not DNX.

Comment: Like the other comment said, stop using DNX, and it is no longer a valid term.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, so does fortify support a .NET Core project?

Comment: @LM10 google it or just search SO. One could say that *this* question is off-topic - why don't you check the product's site?  What is on topic is asking about Fortify's bugs that fail to recognize lambdas, `await` etc. There are many relevant questions about Fortify already